# $q.then doesn't invoke callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

What are the possible reasons for the `then`'s callback of a promise not to be called?
For example:

```
function testPromise() {
  console.log("this gets logged")
  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("this too")
    resolve("test")
    console.log("and this");
    $rootScope.$apply()
    console.log("and this too");
  })
}
testPromise().then(function(result){
  console.log("this never gets logged")
});
```

Am I not seeing something obvious? Thank you.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked **many** times before, though I **think** your specific problem comes from invoking `$rootScope.$apply()` in the return statement, rather than before it, requiring an additional digest. Try adding `$rootScope.$digest()` just before `$rootScope.$apply()`.

Comment: Pretty sure `$q` triggers a scope digest on resolve / reject all by itself. You don't need to add it manually

Comment: I agree with Phil, and actually for some reason I had problems calling $apply() on my example.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers. As it turned out and some of you mentioned it has to do with where I was calling this function from. So calling from a regular function works. Calling from callback of another `then` also worked, but calling from `context.sync().then()` where `context.sync()` is a `Word Add-in`'s promise (and who knows what it actually is) - doesn't. So I ended up converting my function to take a callback, rather then being a promise.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the version of AngularJS you are using.

In AngularJS 1.2 [$q was not a function](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ng/service/$q) and instead required you to create something called a "deferred" and return a promise separately.

However, you should receive an error in the console telling you so if this is this case.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on where you are calling `$rootScope.$apply()` from. If it's during execution period of a digest cycle then your call will cause an error and stop execution of the script.

Your example works perfectly without `$rootScope.$apply()`. Could you provide more context about how you were intending to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.
I guess it's just how you are using $q.
So I made a working example.

In my example I use $q inside a service and delay its response with $timeout
I deleted the $apply() I don't know why are you using it.

```
 app.factory('TestingService', TestingService);
  function TestingService($q, $timeout) {
  return {runPromise:runPromise};
    function runPromise() {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
          console.log("inside my $q")
          $timeout(function(){
            resolve("$q is working fine"); 
          }, 2000); //Lets use $timeout, just to see the result
        });
    };
  }
```

and then

```
TestingService.runPromise().then(
  function(result){
    console.log('result::',result);
    vm.test = result;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/moplin/r0vda86d/

I hope it helps.